# Python dictionary - need only a few pairs - is it better to pop unused pairs or make a new dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Which option is the best for extracting a few things from a big dictionary, pop everything out except the desired pairs or creating a new one? And what about speed/memory?

```
parsed = json.loads(WS) #data
```

Either:

```
parsed2 = {"lat": parsed["lat"],
          "lon": parsed["lon"],
          "time": parsed["time"]}
```

or

```
parsed.pop("alt") 
parsed.pop("delay")
parsed.pop("mcg")
parsed.pop("mds")
parsed.pop("pol")
parsed.pop("sig") #contains another dictionary if it matters speed-wise?
```

This would leave out only the desired pairs.

Also, is it bad "not to make a new one" in the first case:

```
parsed = {"lat": parsed["lat"], (...)}
```

I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in one go

```
fields = ["lat", "lon", "time"]
parsed = {k: v for k, v in json.loads(WS).items() if k in fields}
```

Comment: You should probably use a `set` for fields, i.e. `{'lat', 'lon', 'time'}`. Otherwise, this solution is fine.